# Image not loading through URL in ImageView using Picasso android

Tags: android, picasso

I am using the `Picasso` library to set the image from URL. This URL is working in other programming language but not in **Android**.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(product_modal.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_no_image).into(holder.iv_thumbnail_filled);
```

Comment: what's the url?

Comment: Can you post your image url

Comment: Please put error logcat if you get anything.

Comment: may be  product_modal.getImage() is getting null or empty String

Comment: Copy the URL to a browser to see if the image shows up

Comment: https://woocommerce-195737-729319.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/hoodie_3_front.jpg

Comment: I have checked image on browser and also check the string is is not null and blank

Comment: Are you checking in android 9 (In Pie)?

Comment: If using emulator, be sure it can load the image on browser.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the actual problem that you have faced. Replace `https` to `http` in your URL. Because your site does not have SSL.

Just created a method for loading image

```
    private void loadImage(final ImageView imageView, final String imageUrl){
    Picasso.get()
            .load(imageUrl)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.image_white)
            .into(imageView , new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() { 
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                     String updatedImageUrl;
                    if (imageUrl.contains("https")){
                         updatedImageUrl = imageUrl.replace("https", "http");
                    }else{
                         updatedImageUrl = imageUrl.replace("http", "https");
                    }
                    loadImage(imageView, updatedImageUrl);
                }
            });
}
```

You just need to provide an `imageView` and the image URL. For the first time if image not loaded then its try to replace `https` to `http` and then try load the image.

Using the method by using this:

```
loadImage(holder.iv_thumbnail_filled, product_modal.getImage());
```

And make sure you have Internet Access Permission on AndroidMenifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: product_modal.getImage() gives image URL

Comment: Picasso.get()
    .load(product_modal.getImage())
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_no_image) 
    .into(holder.iv_thumbnail_filled);i have already tried it but not working

Comment: if i replace the https then it is not woking for another urls

Comment: I have tried the URL that you provided in the comment section. Would you provide another image url which is not working?

Comment: http://oliver.netmagnetic.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/bike-black.jpg

Comment: @user9319961 check the updated answer. This URL also worked.

Comment: For both url's this method is working well for me and I have tested with an imageView.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library, they've changed the way of loading images

Please use the below to load image

```
Picasso.get().load(product_modal.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_no_image).into(holder.iv_thumbnail_filled);
```

You can check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206039/squareup-picasso-with-method-unresolved-android-studio) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you have HTTP 504 error, have a try:
Uninstalling the app and installing it again!

Info from [here](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1896).